# Passing integers between listboxes in two separate forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

So here's what I'm looking for. I want two WinForms to load at the same time when I compile the program. Both of them contain two list boxes, listBoxBid and listBoxAsk in Form1 and listBoxBid2 and listBoxAsk2 in Form2. In Form1 you submit bids by typing a value into a textbox and clicking a submit button. When you submit a bid, it should display in both listBoxBid in Form 1 and listBoxBid2 in Form2. This I've had success with...

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  public int getBid(myBid)
    {
      return listBoxBid2.Items.Add(myBid);
    {
{
```

...and then...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form2.Show();
    }

    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    List<int> bids = new List<int>();

private void buttonBid_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   \\some code to convert text to output

    form2.getBid(output);
{
```

So this works. However, in Form2 all the Ask values are made and I want them to show in both listBoxAsk and listBoxAsk2. But when I use the same method as I did with the bids, I get a StackOverflow Exception (which makes sense, since activating form1 activates form2, which then activates another form1...etc.).

So my question is, how can I get the Ask values from Form 2 to Form 1's listBoxAsk. I've tried googling but haven't found a method yet that works :/

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference to `Form1` when instantiating `Form2`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  private readonly Form1 _form1;

  public Form2(Form1 frm) {
      _form1 = frm;
  }

  public int getBid(myBid)
  {
      return listBoxBid2.Items.Add(myBid);
  }
}
```

This allows you to pass the instance of `Form1` along to `Form2` when you create it:

```
form2 = new Form2(this);
```

Then you can write a method in `Form2` that adds items to `Form1`:

```
void AddItemsToMainForm(object[] items) {
    _form1.listBox.Items.AddRange(items);
}
```

Comment: I'm not having luck with this answer. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. Where did you place form2 = new Form2(this); because I keep getting a red underline under "this" where I normally had the variable.

Comment: In your edited question, change this: `Form2 form2 = new Form2();` to this: `Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);`.